# Why isn't the rendered image a readable file?

Tags: rendering, file-format

When I try to render this animation the file is a file I am not familiar with and it's not an image file as I was expecting. I attached some images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You specified a file format but didn't match the file name extension. Your files should be fine, just batch rename them using some external program and add the .jpeg extension to the end.

Comment: The file extensions box is unchecked and the OS doesn't know what kind of file it is. You can manually add it (for example .jpg or. png, etc)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Comments aren't for answering the question.

Comment: Not entirely sure this solves the problem, nor that my comment classifies as a full featured answer.

Comment: Thank you Durante Farrajota Ramos and cegaton that helped a lot and solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the file extension box or type in the file extension manually (.jpg .png etc.)

[image]

Comment: Please give a more detailed description as to what exactly they should do and where in the interface they should do it.