# Why will render not play in Windows?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, video-sequence-editor

I have created this short intro template but ran into a problem. I rendered it out as an FFMPEG video, Container - Mpeg-4, and video codec h.264 (see Fig 1). However, when I looked at the file in the File Explorer this is how it looked (See Fig 2). It would not run in Windows Movies & TV or in blender VSE.

(FYI: rendered in EEVEE.)

IMAGES:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you choose your output path?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77389/why-isnt-the-rendered-image-a-readable-file

Comment: THANK YOU very much. I had forgotten to enable "File Extension"